# Plain html button instead of the Twitter Bootstrap styled button?

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap

I work in IE 9 and want to use Twitter Bootstrap. One of the caveats is square buttons. From a UX stand point the user is not familiar with this. What is the best way to keep the html buttons normal without Twitter Bootstrap styling it?

Comment: Give us some HTML! Do you mean `button` or `input` elements? Also why do you see rounded buttons so problematic? Have you got some user feedback or how have you studied that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by button you mean elements like:

```
<div class="btn">Button</div>
```

Then you can simply overwrite the style:

```
<div class="btn" style="border-radius: 0px">Button</div>
```

A more elegant solution would be to add your own CSS class like `squared`:

```
div.squared {border-radius: 0px;}
```

And use that instead:

```
<div class="btn squared">Button</div>
```

Note also that for cross-browser compatibility, you may need to add browser-specific CSS, totalling in CSS of:

```
div.squared {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}
```